# Let $\mathbb Z[\omega] = \{x + \omega y | x, y \in \mathbb Z\}$ where $\omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0$ Prove that $N(z) = z\bar z = x^2 - xy + y^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $\mathbb Z[\omega] = \{x + \omega y | x, y \in \mathbb Z\}$ where $\omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0$ Let $x+ \omega y \in \mathbb Z[\omega]$ and let $\bar z$ denote the complex conjugate of $z$.

Prove that $N(z) = z\bar z = x^2 - xy + y^2$ and that $N(z_1z_2) = N(z_1)N(z_2)$.

I can write $\omega = \sqrt{-\omega - 1} = i \sqrt{(\omega + 1)}$. However, I cannot achieve the form of $N(z)$ for $z$.

Could someone tell me how to eliminate $\omega$ in the norm expression to obtain $N(z) = x^2 - xy + y^2$?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that $\omega$ satisfies $\omega^2+\omega +1=0$ instead of $\omega^2+1=0$?

Comment: @Sigur. Surely the stated equation is correct! If $\omega$ were $\sqrt{-1}$, then the norm would be $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, this was the reason of my question. I was reading $x^2+y^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zeros of the polynomial $x^2+x+1$ are $\omega$ and $\overline{\omega}$, so
$$
(x^2+x+1)=(x-\omega)(x-\overline{\omega})=x^2-(\omega+\overline{\omega})x+\omega\overline{\omega}
$$
as polynomials. This gives you the relations (by equating coefficients of like powers of $x$)
$$
\omega+\overline{\omega}=-1
$$
and
$$
\omega\overline{\omega}=1.
$$
Can you do it using these two equations?

Comment: Thanks ! - However what number is $\omega$ ? It it allowed to define something in terms of itself ?

Comment: @Nicolas, if you use the quadratic formula to solve it, then you will find that $\omega=(-1\pm i\sqrt3)/2$. We cannot tell which sign applies. Thankfully it doesn't matter here, as the other root is $\overline{\omega}$, so both choices lead to the same answer. Check it out! Note that the first equation implies that $\overline{\omega}=-1-\omega$, so the set $\Bbb{Z}[\omega]$ will turn out the same irrespective of which of these roots you decide to call $\omega$. There is no circular definition here, if you look carefully.

Comment: Thanks alot Jyrki. Now I can move onwards trying to prove $\mathbb Z[\omega]$ is an Euclidian domain.

Comment: Jyrki, could you give me a hint on how to prove $1 - \omega$ is a prime element ? I've proved the ring is an Euclidean domain. My idea is to prove that $1 \in <1 - \omega>$ but this approach doesn't seem to work quite well.

Comment: The norms are integers, so the formula $N(z_1z_2)=N(z_1)N(z_2)$ implies that if the norm is a prime, then so is the element. A few details there that you need to think through :-)

Comment: Ahh, because the ring is Euclidean it is a UFD. We then know every non-zero non-unit element has an irreducible factorization and that irreducibility of an element implies it is prime. Because the norm of $1 - \omega$ is a prime number $ = 3$ it must be irreducible hence prime.

Comment: Also in the proof that the ring is Euclidean is it OK that I carry it out assuming $\omega = -1/2 + i \sqrt(3)/2$ or $\omega = -1/2 - i \sqrt(3)/2$ and then doing it like proving that $\mathbb Z[i]$ is Euclidean (The ring og Gaussian integers) ?

Answer (score 1):

w denotes 'omega' here

z=x+wy

and conjugate(z)
=x+ conj(w)y
=x+ w²y (because conj(w)=w²)

now
N(z) = z×conj(z)
=(x+ wy)(x+w²y)
=x²+w³y²+(x+y)(w+w²)
=x²-(x+y)+y²

We're Done.